# Constructing a probability histogram for p(y)

Tags: r, histogram

I am having some difficulty plotting the probability histogram for the table below

y     1   2   3   4

p(y) 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1

I've tried the command:
hist(p <- c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1), y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4), main = "Frequency Histogram")
but it didn't work. Is there a way for this to construct the probability histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
p <- setNames(c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1), 1:4); barplot(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>